# How to scale a image (dynamic imageviews)

Tags: android, android-imageview, scale

[image]This is my code to create dynamic imageviews. Image get aligned really well but I need to make it small. How can I scale the image?

This is a in a LinearLayout:

```
for(int i=0;i<value1;i++) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(Home.this);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulb);
    image.setScaleX(1);
    image.setScaleY(1);
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    rR.addView(image);
}
```

This is my code to create dynamic imageviews . Image get aligned really well but i need to make it small. How can i scale the image?

Comment: How can you have code inside a LinearLayout, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Also, it looks like you are trying to do something that adapters usually take care of: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html. You can use adapters to build ListViews (like in a contact app) and GridViews (like a gallery app) easily.

Comment: actulay the layout is a linearlayout. I'm just trying to scale my image size

Comment: Well is layout_width and layout_height set correctly? And what do you expect from setScaleX(1)? This is the default scale and technically means "don't rescale my image"

Comment: yeah thank you so much . I found my answer from that link

Answer (score 1):

Please set the proper height and width of your dynamic image view.
Please try below code it's helpful to you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(ImageScalling.this);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200));         
        image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        rR.addView(image);

    }
```

I have set width and height is 200. If you want the show a small image then set less than 200.

Comment: Thnx a lot! I got The answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

For scaling imageview try this link

https://argillander.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/scale-image-into-imageview-then-resize-imageview-to-match-the-image/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of Imageview according to screen size like 20% of height .

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int height = display.getHeight();
    int width = display.getWidth();                                        
    float mReqPercentages =20.0;
    float mCalculatedWidth = (mReqPercentages / 100) * height;

    image.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (mCalculatedWidth * 1.5);
    image.getLayoutParams().width = (int) mCalculatedWidth;
```